# Deploy more than one WebService applications on WSo2 Application server

Tags: web-applications, wso2, application-server

I am new in  web services. I am created  SOAP based web service and try to deploy it on WSO2 application server. It works fine on that.
My question is--> is that possible to deploy more than one web service application on the same WSO2 application server.

Now i deployed the .aar on application server,It works fine. Is that possible to deploy more than one .aar on the server.

Kindly pls give me suggestions  on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy multiple applications in WSO2 Application Server. They could be of different types also. Each app will have a different url context. So you can deploy many applications in the same server.

Go through the [Application Server documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS510/Developing+and+Deploying+Different+Application+Types) to understand more about this.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but the problem is, when i deployed three application's .aar file then only the last deployed will be working fine.If i remove the last two then first will be working fine. It gives error of bean not found in case of multiple Spring web service  applications.

Comment: Make sure they have different service names in `services.xml` file. And also I think .aar file should be Axis2 services. What is the error you get when you have multiple services?

Comment: Yes.arr files are  Axis2 services.When i deployed second .aar file, it will shows the error of "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No bean named 'catCatalogueWS' is defined" which are working in the beginning and all services have differant names.And the goodness is that from second .aar file all services are working fine. I am so much confused about this.